# Regular expression in a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I just needed to know if its possible to have a regular expression inside the definition of a regular expression.

Here is what I am trying to do:
I have defined regular expressions for Integers, Natural numbers, Positive Integers and Negative integers. Now I would like to use these already existing regular expressions to define the regular expression for fraction.

```
Consider
token_int is the regex for integers
token_natural is the regex for natural numbers
token_neg_int is the regex for negative integers

I would like the fraction regex to be defined as:

token_frac = token_int'/'(token_natural | token_neg_int)
```

Comment: If your grammar becomes sufficiently complex, you should consider using a tokenizer/parser, which is more suited to the job. PLY is an excellent Python library for defining a tokenizer/parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand you then yes.  But in the following manner (since regular expressions are strings):

```
token_frac = token_int + '/(' + token_natural + '|' + token_neg_int + ')'
```